# Combinations of Permutations - Is the solution $5^7$ or $7^5$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

An example from my textbook says the following:

Five persons entered the lift cabin on the ground floor of an 8 floor house. Suppose each of them can leave the cabin independently at any floor beginning with the first. Find the total number of ways in which each of the five persons can leave the cabin at any one of the 7 floors.

It provides the solution as:

$$7*7*7*7*7 = 7^5$$

I would assume that since there's 5 people and 7 floors.. it would be the same as 7 questions with 5 choices which is:

$$5*5*5*5*5*5*5 = 5^7$$

Am I wrong? Can someone explain?

Thank you!

Comment: But a person can only leave the lift once. $5^7$ apparently allows one person to leave multiple times or not at all.

Comment: You should think of it as $5$ questions with $7$ choices: each of the $5$ people is asked a question: which floor will you choose? Each of them can give one of $7$ possible answers.

Comment: well your statement "..I would assume that since there's $5$ people and $7$ floors.. it would be the same as $7$ questions with $5$ choices which is..." is wrong. In the fist case each persons choice is $7$ flowers, while in the later each questions choices are $5$ answers...

Comment: I will point out that the original tags "*permutations*" and "*combinations*" do not apply.  The solution for this problem is more fundamental than that, relying on the multiplication principle.  In fact, many problems in introductory combinatorics boils down to this.

Comment: How many ways can we write a floor number on each person's forehead?

Comment: You may be interpreting the question as saying that a person can get out more than once but I'm sure it means each person only gets out only once.

Answer (score 3):

Each person chooses one of $7$ floors:
$$7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7=7^5$$
and if the first floor is already chose a certain person, then that person can not choose any other floor.

Answer (score 3):

#### Wrong Solution:

The problem (as you guessed) lies within the following statement:

> I would assume that since there's 5 people and 7 floors.. it would be
>   the same as 7 questions with 5 choices

One issue with this statement is that "7 questions with 5 choices" implies only one of those choices can be correct (for each question), this would be equivalent to saying that only one person can get off on any floor (which  doesn't really make sense!).

Another problem is that if each question has 5 choices a), b), c), d), e), then the answer to all the questions *could be* a). However, in our case this would be equivalent to saying that person a) got off on all 7 floors (which also doesn't make sense!).

#### Real Solution:

The solution to the problem is that there are 5 people and each of these people can be assigned to any of 7 floors. In other words, each person can take one (and only one) of 7 values. You can think of this as 5 questions each with 7 possible answers.

The answer is then
\begin{align*}
{\text{# of Possible Arrangements}}&=(\text{# of Options for Person 1})\times\cdots\times (\text{# of Options for Person 5})\\
&={\underbrace{7\times\cdots\times7}_{5 \text{ times}}}=7^5.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Counting by floors is far more complicated than you suggest.

For the first floor you have two choices for each person in the lift (exit or stay), a total of $2^5=32$.

Now consider the second floor. You only have choices for those remaining. So if $k$ people got out on the first floor, then you have $2^{5-k}$ choices for the second floor. There are ${5\choose k}$ ways of picking $k$ people to get out on the first floor. So you have a total of ${5\choose0}2^5+{5\choose1}2^4+\dots+{5\choose4}2^1+{5\choose5}2^0=243=3^5$ choices for the 1st and 2nd floors.

Now consider the 3rd floor. There are ${5\choose0}{5\choose k}+{5\choose1}{4\choose k-1}+\dots+{5\choose k}{5-k\choose0}=2^k{5\choose k}$ ways for $k$ to get off on the 1st and 2nd floors, and hence $2^{5-k}{5\choose k}$ for $5-k$ to get off on the 1st and 2nd floors. There are then $2^k$ choices (leave or stay) for the remaining $k$. So the total number of choices for the first three floors is $2^5({5\choose0}+{5\choose1}+\dots+{5\choose5})=4^5$.

And so on.

[I think I have done enough to make clear that in combinatorics it is critical to choose the right way to approach a problem. A poor way can get extremely complicated, even if it eventually gives the right answer.]

Answer (score 2):

The first person can choose $7$ ways on  which floor to  leave the cabin. Given one of the choices out of those $7$ the second person can choose again in $7$ ways which floor to leave  the cabin. Similarly for the rest of the three persons. So the answer is $7\times 7\times 7\times 7 \times 7=7^5$.

Advice: when you are confused with these kind of problem, make the numerical value small and try to write out explicitly how many possibilities are there. For example let's say there are two floors and two people. Let's name the person A and B

Possible ways (A-First, B-first), (A-First, B-Second ), (A-Second, B-first), (A-Second, B-Second). 
So 4 possible ways.

Let's say now 3 people A,B,C and two floors 
Possible ways (A-First, B-first, C-First ), (A-First, B-first , C-Second ), (A-first, B-Second, C-first), (A-First , B-Second, C-Second). (A-Second, B-first, C-First ), (A-Second, B-first , C-Second ), (A-SECOND, B-Second, C-first), (A-SECOND , B-Second, C-Second).

So possible 8 ways.

Do the same thing for 4  people and 3 ways.

You can easily see the pattern is $\text{No.of floors  }^{\text{No. Of people}}$

This is the best way to convince yourself that the answer is true, in fact you yourself can guess the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers here already. Just to find a question to which the answer **is** $5^7$, for illustration of the difference:

> The floors of a building are being sold as separate items. There are 5 people bidding for the floors. Each floor will be sold to only one bidder. In how many different ways might the floor ownership be allocated?

Note that here, each floor "chooses" one person.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is definitely $7^5$.

Numbering your people arbitrarily, the first person can choose any of 7 floors to exit, as can the 2nd, as can the 3rd and so on.

$7\times7\times7\times7\times7=7^5$